# I'm getting a core dump

Tags: c, coredump, atoi

I'm trying to read in a int number as the height for a tree I'm building the input is

./htree testcase height

I'm trying to save it in the struct

```
struct arguments
{
    uint64_t length;
uint8_t* file;
    uint32_t threadNum;
int heightTree;
};
```

the part that is giving me the core dump is inside main where I'm trying to assign the height.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct arguments *args;
    int32_t fd;
    uint32_t nblocks;
    struct stat hold;
    // input checking
    if (argc != 3)
        Usage(argv[0]);

    // open input file
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // use fstat to get file size
    fstat(fd, &hold);
    off_t file_size= hold.st_size;



    // calculate nblocks
    nblocks= file_size/ BSIZE;

    (*args).heightTree= atoi(argv[2]);

    (*args).threadNum=0;
    uint32_t nthreads= (1<<((*args).heightTree+1));
    (*args).length= nblocks/ nthreads;



(*args).file= mmap(NULL, hold.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE,fd,0);
    printf(" no. of blocks = %u \n", nblocks);


    close(fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please post code that can be compiled and tested that produces the result you are concerned about (a MCVE)

Comment: We need to see all the relevant code, and how it's getting called. What does `argv[2]` have in it? How do you know? `printf` it to be sure. Are you sure it's that line that causes the segfault?  How do you know? Have you tried the program with that line commented out?

Comment: Where's the part where you assign a value to `args`?  (it's a pointer, you should point it at something before you dereference it).

Comment: `struct arguments *args;` is an uninitialized pointer. Its value is indeterminate, which effectively means you are trying to write to random memory. Allocate some memory first: try simply removing `*` (`struct arguments args;`, `args.heightTree = ...`).

Comment: `args->threadNum` is the accepted way of writing `(*args).threadNum`, both work but 99% of readers will go - 'huh?!'

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues

**Save time.  Enable all warnings**

Example:

```
(*args).heightTree= atoi(argv[2]);
warning: 'args' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

**Uninitialized pointer**

Use a `struct` rather than an uninitialized pointer. [@Oka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905395/im-getting-a-core-dump/71905810#comment127062115_71905395)

```
// struct arguments *args;
// ...
// (*args).heightTree= atoi(argv[2]);

struct arguments args;
...
args.heightTree = atoi(argv[2]);
```

**Types changes involving sign-ness**

Avoid casual types changes involving sign-ness.  Robust code looks for problem values.
Declare object when needed, not far away from their first use.

```
// uint32_t nblocks;
//...
// off_t file_size= hold.st_size;
// nblocks= file_size/ BSIZE;

off_t file_size = hold.st_size;
if (file_size < 0) {
   Handle_unusual_file_size();
}
off_t nblocks = file_size / BSIZE;
```